# Nokia Here Maps calculating the centroid of a polygon (e.g triangle) generates wrong results

Tags: javascript, here-api

As the topic says i have a polygon and want to calculate the center of mass (centroid). I take the geo-coordinates, transform them into pixel cooridinates use the formula found on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid and transform the the calculated pixels back into geo-coordinates.

The result seems just wrong (i can't post pictures). The relevant code snippet is:

```
    this.drawPolygonCenter = function (mapService, coords) {
            var sumY = 0;
            var sumX = 0;
            var partialSum = 0;
            var sum = 0;
            var cm = mapService.getCurrentMapReference();
            var points = [];
            coords.forEach(function (c, idx) {
                points.push(cm.geoToPixel(c));
                console.log("x: " + points[idx].x + " y: " + points[idx].y);
            });
            var n = points.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
                partialSum = points[i].x * points[i + 1].y - points[i + 1].x * points[i].y;
                sum += partialSum;
                sumX += (points[i].x + points[i + 1].x) * partialSum;
                sumY += (points[i].y + points[i + 1].y) * partialSum;
            }

            var area = 0.5 * sum;
            var div = 6 * area;
            var x1 = sumX / div;
            var y1 = sumY / div;
            console.log("Centroid: x= " + x1 + " y= " + y1); // debug
            var pinLocation = cm.pixelToGeo(Math.ceil(x1), Math.ceil(y1));
            var pin = this.createCenterPin(pinLocation);

            cm.objects.add(new nokia.maps.map.StandardMarker(pinLocation)); // debug
```

Comment: What kind of wrong is it ? Any chance that its actually the centerpoint of upperleft-corner and the polygon points ?

Comment: Nope I don't think it is the case you describe. I'll uploaded a picture at [link](http://www.pic-upload.de/view-22911875/wrong-centroid.png.html). As you can see the centroid is not correct. I know I'm projecting on a plain and there is an error when doing so, but this is a fairly small area and the error shouldn't be that great. The funny thing is, if i make the triangle smaller the error gets much bigger.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon your calculation has a rounding error is due switching between pixels and lat/longs - there is no need to do this - you can work with lat/longs directly.

You can add a `getCentroid()` method to the `Polygon` class as shown:

```
 nokia.maps.map.Polygon.prototype.getCentroid = function (arg) {
    var signedArea = 0,
      len = this.path.getLength(),
      centroidLongitude = 0,
      centroidLatitude = 0;


    for (i=0; i < len; i++){
      var a = this.path.get(i),
      b = this.path.get( i + 1 < len ? i + 1 : 0);

      signedArea +=
        ((a.longitude * b.latitude) -  (b.longitude * a.latitude));
      centroidLongitude += (a.longitude + b.longitude) *
        ((a.longitude * b.latitude) - (b.longitude * a.latitude));
      centroidLatitude += (a.latitude + b.latitude) *
        ((a.longitude * b.latitude) - (b.longitude * a.latitude));
    }

    signedArea = signedArea /2;

    centroidLongitude   = centroidLongitude/ (6 * signedArea);
    centroidLatitude   = centroidLatitude/ (6 * signedArea);

    return new  nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(centroidLatitude, centroidLongitude);
  };
```

You can call `polygon.getCentroid()` (e.g. to add a marker) as follows:

```
 map.objects.add(new nokia.maps.map.Marker(polygon.getCentroid()));
```

Note, you may still get some edge effects of your  `Polygon` crosses the 180th meridian.(use the `isIDL()`method to check) . In this case you may need to add 360 to each latitude prior to making the calculations, and substract it from the final result.